# Username login bypasses password input and proceeds directly to else statement

Tags: c, scanf, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char username[12] = "admin";
  char password[12] = "admin";


  system("color 9f");
  system("cls");
  login:
  printf("                        ---------------------------------- \n");
  printf("                       |                                  |\n");
  printf("                       |      WELCOME TO OMAR WATER'S     |\n");
  printf("                       |             INVENTORY            |\n");
  printf("                       |              SYSTEM              |\n");
  printf("                       |                                  |\n");
  printf("                        ---------------------------------- \n\n\n");
  printf("Please Log-In...\n\n");
  printf("Username: ");
  scanf("%c", &username);

  if (username == "admin"){
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    scanf("%c", &password);

    if (password == "admin"){
      printf("\n\nWELCOME ", &username);
    }else{
      printf("INVALID PASSWORD");
      getchar();
      system("cls");
      goto login;
    }

  }else {
    printf("INVALID USERNAME");
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    goto login;
  }


  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

console application; c (not c++);

I am currently in the part of my program where I want to ask for a preset username and password. When I enter the correct username, instead of asking for the password, it just flashes the 'enter password' and jumps directly to the else statement. and then does the goto login; **code**.

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to make this work? By the way, I am using dev-c++ IDE.

Comment: This is a very common problem that happens to programmers used to compare strings with `==` in languages like c++ for example, which has a `string` type, there is no such thing in c, and you need to compare strings one character at a time, there are of course functions in the standard library that do this for you efficiently, and are easy to use.

Comment: IMHO, dup is not proper . This Q has __multiple__ issues. Would you mind re-cosidering the closing Mr @iharob?

Answer (score 6):

**Point 1**

In your code

```
 scanf("%c", &username);
```

is wrong, it will scan only *one* `char` to `username[0]`, leaving all other inputs into the buffer, which will be *automatically* read in later calls.

use

```
scanf("%11s", username);
```

to *scan* for *string* inputs.

**Point 2**

You don't comapre *strings* like

```
 username == "admin"
```

you need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: @theblackaccord (_I blame caching..._) Please see the updated answer and the link there.